# WPF Combobox SelectedItem Problem

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, prism

I am failing in achieving a very simple functionality from a WPF ComboBox.

My ComboBox needs to list a collection of values. This works fine. The value id is also saved succesfully  in the database. The problem is that when i want to open the window in edit mode, the combo stays empty. Here is the code :

```
            <ComboBox Height="28" 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                  Name="cmbActivity"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Unit.UnitActivities}"
                  SelectedValuePath="Id"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=UnitActivityId}"
                  Style="{StaticResource comboBoxInError}" 
                  Width="200" 
                  Margin="6" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Text="{Binding Path=ActivityTime.Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
                <Binding ElementName="cmbActivity" Path="UnitActivityId" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <ExceptionValidationRule />
                        <val:NotEmptyValidationRule />
                        <val:UnitResTimeOverlapValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

I understand my problem is somewhere in the SelectedItem section, but i just could not figure where and why.

Please help..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer for the original problem. This is idenctical to : [WPF Cloned/Detached object edit problem - what is the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865738/wpf-cloned-detached-object-edit-problem-what-is-the-standard)

1. First implement your cloneable object container :

   ```
   public class ClonableObjectContainer : Object , ICloneable
   {
       private Object data;

       public ClonableObjectContainer(Object obj)
       {
           data = obj;
       }

       public Object Data
       {
           get { return data; }
       }

       public object Clone()
       {
           return (ClonableObjectContainer)this.MemberwiseClone();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then use this object with its Clone method to create your detached edit object:

   ```
            ClonableObjectContainer coc = new ClonableObjectContainer(actor);
            EntityObject editEntity = (EntityObject)coc.Data;
   ```
3. After performing changes, detach the original object from the ObjectContext
   , attach the cloned object, change its state to `EntityState.Modified` and gracefully save:

   ```
           ContextManager.CurrentObjectContext.Detach(oldItem);
           ContextManager.CurrentObjectContext.Attach((IEntityWithKey)item);
           ContextManager.CurrentObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(item, EntityState.Modified); 
           ContextManager.Save();
   ```

Hope it helps...
Oran

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<Binding ElementName="cmbActivity" Path="UnitActivityId" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
```

to:

```
<Binding Path="UnitActivityId" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
```

by removing the ElementName. It makes no sense to set the binding source to itself because the data context will infer this by default.

Comment: Thank you! Although you are right, the problem source is totaly different and happens because i use a cloned object to edit. I will post another question about it. +1 for you!!